# SVProgressHUD iOS8 Replace circle with animation

Tags: ios, iphone

My Developer is using `SVProgressHUD` to show loading screen. Is it possible to replace the circle with image animation (a sequence of images)

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cemolcay/GiFHUD with gif image

Comment: Can you check in its github page. It has some methods to set info image, success image and error image if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Ashish's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3202193/ashish-kakkad) suggestion of [GifHUD](https://github.com/cemolcay/GiFHUD) is fine but you could use the `UIImageView`'s `animationImages`[API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages). You should be able to just set the images and the duration to get the effect you are looking for. Doing so would reduce your 3rd party dependencies from 2 to 0 which is always a win in my book.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question to ask "your developer", not a question to ask the community. Modifying the 3rd party library or implementing custom functionality like this is always possible, but if it should/could be done is dependent on many circumstances.

To directly answer your question, you can just replace the centered animation with a UIImageView and load a series of images into it and start animating it. This is not a difficult task at all. Implementing this into the current library means complications with future maintenance alongside possible other issues.